Index not being used depending on parameter binding & charset
Question
Why is my index being ignored under certain circumstances, causing slow execution times. I tracked down the cause to a combination of the use of UNION ALL + chosen PHP database API + selected charset + used parameter binding implementation.
Setup
I've created a view my_view which looks like this:
SELECT type FROM table1

UNION ALL

SELECT type FROM table2

Both table1 and table2 have the same structure, which looks like this:
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    type INT NOT NULL,
    ... -- some more data columns
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE INDEX my_idx ON table1 (type);


Now I want to select all records where type = 1. This should be fairly simple:
SELECT * FROM my_view WHERE type = 1;

Doing an EXPLAIN for this query yields the following result:
┌────┬─────────────┬────────────┬───────┬───────────────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬──────┬─────────────┐
│ id │ select_type │ table      │ type  │ possible_keys │ key    │ key_len │ ref    │ rows │ Extra       │
╞════╪═════════════╪════════════╪═══════╪═══════════════╪════════╪═════════╪════════╪══════╪═════════════╡
│  1 │ PRIMARY     │ <derived2> │ ALL   │               │        │         │        │ 110  │ Using where │
│  2 │ DERIVED     │ table1     │ const │ my_idx        │ my_idx │ 5       │ const  │ 72   │ Using index │
│  3 │ UNION       │ table2     │ const │ my_idx        │ my_idx │ 5       │ const  │ 38   │ Using index │
└────┴─────────────┴────────────┴───────┴───────────────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴──────┴─────────────┘

Running the actual SELECT statements in my SQL console works perfectly fine and is super fast.
Issue
This changes when I use PHP to execute the query. Depending on the database connection API (e.g. mysqli, PDO) my database decides to not use the index for my view - using the exact same query from before:
┌────┬─────────────┬────────────┬───────┬───────────────┬────────┬─────────┬─────┬──────────┬─────────────┐
│ id │ select_type │ table      │ type  │ possible_keys │ key    │ key_len │ ref │ rows     │ Extra       │
╞════╪═════════════╪════════════╪═══════╪═══════════════╪════════╪═════════╪═════╪══════════╪═════════════╡
│ 1  │ PRIMARY     │ <derived2> │ ALL   │               │        │         │     │ 56247595 │ Using where │
│ 2  │ DERIVED     │ table1     │ index │               │ my_idx │ 5       │     │ 34706361 │ Using index │
│ 3  │ UNION       │ table2     │ index │               │ my_idx │ 5       │     │ 21541234 │ Using index │
└────┴─────────────┴────────────┴───────┴───────────────┴────────┴─────────┴─────┴──────────┴─────────────┘

Debugging
My debugging revealed the following combinations to be using the index (✅) or not using the index (❌):




API
charset
extra (methods / options)




✅
mysqli
latin1 (default)
->execute_query($sql, [$type])


❌
mysqli
latin1 (default)
->prepare(); ->bind_param(); ->execute(); ->get_result()


❌
mysqli
->set_charset('utf8mb4')
->execute_query($sql, [$type])


❌
mysqli
->set_charset('utf8mb4')
->prepare(); ->bind_param(); ->execute(); ->get_result()


✅
PDO
latin1 (default)
ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = true (default)


✅
PDO
latin1 (default)
->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false)


✅
PDO
new PDO("...charset=utf8mb4", ...)
ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = true (default)


❌
PDO
new PDO("...charset=utf8mb4", ...)
->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false)



I can't make sense out of this. What is going on here?
Version Info

MariaDB 10.6.18
PHP 8.2.26

Running EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ... and SHOW WARNINGS afterwards yield also the same result for all tests:
┌───────┬──────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Level │ Code │ Message                                                                                                  │
├───────┼──────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Note  │ 1003 │ /* select#1 */ select `my_view`.`type` AS `type` from `my_database`.`my_view` where `my_view`.`type` = 1 │
└───────┴──────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

When using a subquery instead of a view, the result of the Message column of SHOW WARNINGS changes.
Query:
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT type from table1 UNION ALL SELECT type from table2
) AS q WHERE type = ?;

SHOW WARNINGS;

Results:
Output of all tests marked with ✅ (WHERE condition is copied into subquery):
/* select#1 */
SELECT q.type AS type
FROM (
    /* select#2 */
    SELECT table1.type AS type
    FROM my_database.table1
    WHERE table1.type = 1
    
    UNION ALL
    
    /* select#3 */
    SELECT table2.type AS type
    FROM my_database.table2
    WHERE table2.type = 1
) q
WHERE q.type = 1;

Output of all tests marked with ❌ (WHERE condition is NOT copied into subquery):
/* select#1 */
SELECT q.type AS type
FROM (
    /* select#2 */
    SELECT table1.type AS type
    FROM my_database.table1
    
    UNION ALL
                            
    /* select#3 */
    SELECT table2.type AS type
    FROM my_database.table2
) q
WHERE q.type = 1;

A SQL/PHP reproducer can be found here:
https://phpize.online/sql/mariadb115/a1c61a1321ba2adfc689bd9e87e75ad9/php/php82/c602157f683d216f384ec3e56833df9b/
I've filed a bug report for this, which can be found here:
https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-35561
Optimizer Traces
I've enabled MariaDB's optimizer trace by setting optimizer_trace to enabled=on. After running the queries, I individually checked the trace with
SELECT * FROM information_schema.optimizer_trace

A diff of both outputs can be found here:
https://www.diffchecker.com/DX1zel8b/

What type did you specify in bind_param? Did you specify i or s?

This may be relevant https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html although from what I understand it should not apply in your case.

Optimizer is a complex piece of software. It's often difficult to understand why it chose this path and not the other. For situations like this, you can pass the arguments using bindValue specifying the type as int. This will cast the argument to int and prevent any string comparison. This could even be a bug in MariaDB's optimizer and it might have even been fixed already in newer versions.

Your view, as described, makes no sense, because it would return a single column type where all the rows would have the same value you used in the SELECT. If that were true, you'd be much better served by using COUNT().
So, I suspect that to be a simplified version of the view, and for the real view to contain other columns... which might - for example - have different charsets in the two tables, leading to different UNION conversions and strategies.

@Dharman type is an integer column, so I specified i. Doing the same thing on another table with a TEXT column and s still yields the same result.

@LSerni Yes, you're right, my example is an oversimplification. My VIEW is much more complex, but I tracked it down to this minimal reproducer. I've checked your suspicion with the charsets, but all of the tables I am trying to join have the same charset/collation. You could even use a UNION with the same table twice and the index wouldn't be used (e.g. SELECT * FROM users UNION ALL SELECT * FROM users)

Use s with the integer column and you will have the same results.

It looks like the first test involved dozens of rows, but the second involved millions.  Are they on Dev vs Production?

Even if you had said (or the API had generated) WHERE type='1', type conversion should not have been a problem.  (The problem occurs with WHERE varchar_col = integer.)

Please turn on the general log to see what the constructed query was.  And please provide EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT ... if possible.

@RickJames All executions are targeting the same database. The first test involves dozens of rows, because my index is being used (at least EXPLAIN puts it this way when executing the EXPLAIN statement). The second test shows the real row count of the tables because my index is not being used.

@RickJames I've added the output of EXPLAIN EXTENDED and SHOW WARNINGS to my post. Unfortunately they are also the same for all tests.

@Dharman I've added a reproducer to my post. Even with MariaDB 11.5 this is still reproducible. I suspect that this really is a bug in MariaDB then.

Apparently, the server neglects to use indexes if it suspects there might be a collation mismatch. You should check the general log and/or dump the @@system variables before the query to verify what  parameters are set.
I have had a query work with one collation but not another, with a mismatch error that as far as I understand should never have happened: SELECT 1 FROM tableWithOneIntegerColumnOnlyAndNoIndexes WHERE id =1 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci; (it fails if I use the legacy swedish collation).
